How to disable the "Upload Image" button in unlayer using vue-email-editor?
I’m using vue-email-editor (a Vue wrapper for unlayer) to integrate an email editor in my Vue 3 project. Everything works fine, but I want to disable the "Upload Image" button that allows users to upload their own images. I've been unable to find a solution in the documentation or source code.
Here’s my current setup:
I’ve initialized the editor with the following configuration:
<template>
  <div>
    <EmailEditor
      ref="emailEditor"
      :appearance="emailEditorConfits.appearance"
      :options="emailEditorConfits.options"
      :tools="emailEditorConfits.tools"
      :project-id="emailEditorConfits.projectId"
      @ready="editorLoaded"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { EmailEditor } from 'vue-email-editor';

const emailEditor = ref(null);

const emailEditorConfits = {
  appearance: {
    panels: {
      tools: { dock: 'right' }
    }
  },
  options: {
    features: {
      userUploads: false,
    },
    imageUploader: {
      shouldRender: {
        dropzone: false,         // Disable dropzone for image uploads
        uploadButton: false,     // Disable the upload button
        userUploads: true,       // Keep user uploaded images visible
        stockImages: true,       // Enable stock images
        moreImages: true,        // Enable more images
      },
    },
  },
  tools: {},
  projectId: <abc-123>,
};

const editorLoaded = () => {
  emailEditor.value.registerProvider('userUploads', function (params, done) {
    const images = [
      {
        id: Date.now(),
        location: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/500',
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        contentType: 'image/png',
        source: 'user'
      }
    ];
    done(images);
  });
};
</script>

What I’ve Tried:

I’ve attempted to disable the "Upload Image" button by setting shouldRender.uploadButton and shouldRender.dropzone to false within the imageUploader configuration, but the button and dropzone are still visible.
I've looked through the unlayer documentation and vue-email-editor issues but haven't found a way to specifically disable the "Upload Image" button.
I’ve checked the node_modules code of ImageUploader, and the relevant part seems to allow customization through shouldRender, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected.

Question:
How can I disable the "Upload Image" button in unlayer when using the vue-email-editor package? Is there any way to fully hide this button or the entire user-upload option?
I appreciate any guidance or examples on how to achieve this!
